# Right-continuity of filtrations on product spaces

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, product-space

Let $(\Omega^1, \mathcal{F}^1)$ and $(\Omega^2,\mathcal{F}^2)$ be two measurable space and let $(\mathcal{F}^2_s)_{s \geq 0}$ be a filtration on $(\Omega^2,\mathcal{F}^2)$. Moreover, let $t\geq 0$ be fixed.

My question is the following: Does the following equation hold true?:

$\mathcal{F}^1 \otimes \bigcap_{\varepsilon>0} \mathcal{F}^2_{t+ \varepsilon}
= \bigcap_{\varepsilon>0} \big[ \mathcal{F}^1 \otimes \mathcal{F}^2_{t+ \varepsilon} \big]$

Comment: For any $\varepsilon>0$ it is clear that $\mathcal{F}^1 \otimes \bigcap_{\delta>0} \mathcal{F}^2_{t+ \delta} \subseteq \mathcal{F}^1 \otimes \mathcal{F}^2_{t+\varepsilon}$. Thus, we see that $\mathcal{F}^1 \otimes \bigcap_{\delta>0} \mathcal{F}^2_{t+ \delta} \subseteq \bigcap_{\varepsilon>0} \big[ \mathcal{F}^1 \otimes \mathcal{F}^2_{t + \varepsilon} \big]$. But the other direction si not clear to me...